# expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
//To use fgets and printf I need to include stdio header

#include <string.h>
//To use strlen I need to include string header

#define MAXLINE 100 /* maximum input line length */

int suffix(char str[], char c);

/*
  The function suffix prints all the substrings that 
  (1) starts with the letter stored in the variable 'c' 
  (2) included in the string str[]

  Function should return the number of substrings.

 */


int main()
{
    char user_input[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char ch = 0;
    int counter = 0;


    printf(" Please enter a string (up to 100 characters) and then press enter ");

    /*
    This will store a maximum of MAXLINE characters into the string from the standard input 
    and it will ensure it is null-terminated. 
    The fact that we've limited the input to the size of the array declared earlier 
    ensures that there's no possibility of buffer overruns.
    */
    fgets(user_input, MAXLINE, stdin);

    //Then let's clear the pesky newline that's been entered into the string using strlen:
    user_input[strlen(user_input)-1] = '\0';

    printf(" Please enter a character and then press enter ");
    ch = getchar();
    while ( getchar() != '\n' );

    counter = suffix(user_input,ch);

    return 0;
}



int suffix(char str[], char c);
{
  int i=0,j=0;

  for (i=0 ; (i < MAXLINE-1) ; i++)
  {
    if (str[i] == c)
      for (j=i ; (j < MAXLINE-1) ; j++)
    printf("%c", str[j]);
    count++;
    printf("\n");
  }

  return count;

}
```

I also wrote the following make file:

```
mystr: my_str.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall my_str.o -o mystr

my_str.o: my_str.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall my_str.c -o my_str.o
```

However, I get the following compilation errors:

```
VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Exercises/Assignments/my_str$ make
gcc -c -ansi -Wall my_str.c -o my_str.o
my_str.c:2:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
my_str.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
my_str.c: In function ‘main’:
my_str.c:38:5: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
my_str.c:38:15: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
my_str.c:45:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘suffix’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
my_str.c:25:9: warning: variable ‘counter’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
my_str.c: At top level:
my_str.c:52:5: error: conflicting types for ‘suffix’
my_str.c:52:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
my_str.c:45:15: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘suffix’ was here
my_str.c:53:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
make: *** [my_str.o] Error 1
VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Exercises/Assignments/my_str$
```

Please assist with "expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token" error.

Why conflicting types of suffix? why implicit declaration (each function in C must be declared at the beginning of the program so I it`s not clear to me what is wrong here)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what clcto has said, you  need to remove the semicolon from the start of your function definition:

```
int suffix(char str[], char c)
{
    ...
}
```

And you need to declare the variable `count` before you use it:

```
    int i=0,j=0;
    int count = 0;
```

Then your code will compile (though it may not do what you expect).

Answer (score 8):

You are compiling with `-ansi` which according to [`man gcc`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/gcc1.html) disables C++ style comments (`//`):

> ```
>   -ansi
>        In C mode, support all ISO C90 programs.  In C++ mode, remove GNU
>        extensions that conflict with ISO C++.
>
>        This turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with
>        ISO C90 (when compiling C code), or of standard C++ (when compiling
>        C++ code), such as the "asm" and "typeof" keywords, and predefined
>        macros such as "unix" and "vax" that identify the type of system
>        you are using.  It also enables the undesirable and rarely used ISO
>        trigraph feature.  For the C compiler, it disables recognition of
>        C++ style // comments as well as the "inline" keyword.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I applied all your suggestions + make some more extra fixes, and now it works like a charm.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/*To use fgets and printf I need to include stdio header*/

#include <string.h>
/*To use strlen I need to include string header*/

#define MAXLINE 100 /* maximum input line length */

int suffix(char str[], char c);

/*
  The function suffix prints all the substrings that 
  (1) starts with the letter stored in the variable 'c' 
  (2) included in the string str[]
  (3) returns the number of substrings
 */


int main()
{
    char user_input[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char ch = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i < MAXLINE-1 ; ++i)
      user_input[i] = 0;


    printf(" \nPlease enter a string (up to 100 characters) and then press enter\n ");


    for (i=0; i < MAXLINE-1 && ( ch=getchar())!= EOF && ch !='\n'; ++i)
      user_input[i] = ch;

    user_input[i] ='\0';

    printf(" \nPlease enter a character and then press enter\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);

    counter = suffix(user_input,ch);

    printf("substring counter is = %d ", counter);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}



int suffix(char str[], char c)
{
  int i=0,j=0;
  int count = 0;

  printf("\n########################\n\n");
  printf("Substrings are as follows: \n");

  for (i=0 ; (i < MAXLINE-1) ; i++)
  {
    if (str[i] == c)
    {
      for (j=i ; (j < MAXLINE-1) ; j++)
    printf("%c", str[j]);

      count++;
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  if (count == 0)
      printf("There are no substrings which begin with the specified character\n");

  return count;

}
```